# How to exclude a category within channel:form

Tags: categories, safecracker

I am using the following code within channel:form on EE 2.9

Categories:
{category_menu}

{select_options}

{/category_menu}

The issue is that all my categories show up, I would like the limit it to one of my categories.

I have tried using category_group and category="5" but nothing worked.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your entire template code? This will help us help you better :)

Comment: <div>
      {category_menu}
      
      <select name="category[]" id="categories" category="5" size="4" multiple="multiple">
       {select_options}
      </select>
      {/category_menu}
     </div>

Comment: It would be easier to read if you just update your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you should be able to set `category="5"` take a look at the bit about [parameters](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#category).

Please update your question with your template code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want people to be able to choose categories in your channel form, you can just use the category="y" parameter in your channel form tag as Mark said:

```
{exp:channel:form category="y"...}
```

But, if you do still want to show a select menu etc:
It's not documented from what I can see, but you can use the show_group parameter within the categories tag (an alternative to the category_menu tag see https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#categories).

Then you could use a conditional within that to only output a certain category. Try the following code:

```
{categories show_group="x"}
{if '{category_id}' == y}
 <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
{/if}
{/categories}
```

There may well be another parameter for the categories tag which just lets you limit to a particular ID directly without looping.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
{category_menu}
<select name="category[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">
{exp:query sql="SELECT cat_name, cat_id FROM exp_categories WHERE group_id='5'"}
<option value='{cat_id}'>{cat_name}</option>
{/exp:query}
</select>
{/category_menu}
```

In the past, I've tried different versions of category_group=”#” or cat_id=”#” or category=”#”, but all versions returned all categories.